# Problems making a button show and hide content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just trying to come up with a button to hide content based on a example I've seen that works.

HTML

```
<button id="button">Test</button><br/><br/>
<div id="panel">Test Panel</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").toggle(function() {
        if $("#panel").css("display") == "none" {
            $("#panel").html("Show");
        } else {
            $("#panel").html("Hide");
        };
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#panel {display:none;}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Toggle is deprecated**.. Just attach a click event to the button and use the toggle method for the `panel`

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#panel").toggle();
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxTb/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been trying to figure this out for the last 45 minutes!

Comment: @JoeKasavage.. Glad to have helped :)